# Express routing trouble - POST 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, post

Something just isn't connecting properly when I attempt to use routes specified within **login.js** for **login.component.js**.

It's strange because when I change `axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login/add3', user)` (**/add3**) to `axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login/add', user)` (**/add**) it performs the POST correctly, which leads me to believe it either isn't connected or it's connected to a different route than I specified.

[Link to 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1EUB.png)

Relevent Files: *app.js, login.js, login.component.js, login.model.js*

**app.js** ↓

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";
import LoginUser from "./components/login.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <br/>
      <Route path="/" exact component={ExercisesList} />
      <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
      <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise} />
      <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginUser} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**login.js** ↓

```
let Login = require('../models/login.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Login.find()
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add3').post((req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  const newUser = new Login({
    username,
    password
  });

  newUser.save()
    .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

**login.component.js** ↓

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class LoginUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onChangePassword(e) {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    console.log(user);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login/add3', user)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group"> 
            <input  type="text"
                required
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Username"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                />
            <input  type="text"
                required
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.onChangePassword}
                />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" className="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**login.model.js** ↓

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const loginSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const Login = mongoose.model('Login', loginSchema);

module.exports = Login;
```

Sorry if this is a common question or if there's just a super easy answer, I'm clearly new to ReactJS so I figured I'd just ask others who are far more knowledgeable on the subject

Comment: **server.js** uses

`const loginRouter = require('./routes/login');
app.use('/login', loginRouter);`
if that's relevant

Comment: if the `add` works, that means you do have a `/add` route installed, please look around or just search `/add` or see if you have a plugin or something to add lots of routes for you.

Comment: can you share your main/index/app node js file where you use express, routes etc2x

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on accident... for future reference, just restart the connection to your database! Didn't know that could cause an issue, but here's to learning.